# Evince resume reading at last pint

Tags: evince

Linux's PDF reader "Evince" will save where you are in a book so that the next time you open it it jumps to that page and position.

I was wondering where is this stored? What file does evince read from to know where I last was in each of my books?

Answer (score 0):

The data about files which **evince** has opened are in **~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home**, but I have no idea what the format is: the magic number DA1A gives no clue.

The file names are in there, so I guess the exit positions are in there too, but they are not adjacent to the file names, which are a sequence of null-terminated strings.

There are other file names in the file which have no obvious connection with **evince**, so the file may be used by other applications as well.